Getting false positive on rule "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value."
What is wrong with my eslint (?) config?
I have this code:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function Canvas() {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");

    if (!context || !(context instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)) {
      return;
    }

    context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={600} height={600}>
      test
    </canvas>
  );
}

and ESLint in my VSCode complains about the following things:

and

which is weird, because it understands the type of the context variable.
My tsconfig.json looks like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "references": []
}

and my .eslintrc.json looks like this:
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": "off"
  }
}

(Btw, this is a fresh NextJs created with create-next-app using latest version as of today.)

I have tried restarting VSCode.
I have tried restarting the ESLint Server within VSCode.
It does not work with adding env: browser in the eslint config.
[EDIT]: I get the same linting errors if I run my linter from the terminal.

It looks like it is only types from the DOM that get this problem. If I create my own little object it all works as expected.
